# Why won't my PlotRange change?

Tags: plotting, manipulate, animation

I'm trying to expand the x-axis, but it won't change:

```
xy[t_, m1_, m2_] := {S1[t, m1, m2, V1ie, V2ie], y};
zy[t_, m1_, m2_] := {S2[t, m1, m2, V1ie, V2ie], y};
traj1 := Table[
   xy[t, m1, m2], {t, 0, 10, 100}, {m1, 0.01, 6, 100}, {m2, 0.01, 6}];
traj2 := Table[
   zy[t, m1, m2], {t, 0, 10, 100}, {m1, 0.01, 6, 100}, {m2, 0.01, 6}];   
Manipulate[
 Show[ListPlot[traj1, PlotRange -> {{-1.5, 4}, {0, 1}}], 
  ListPlot[traj2, PlotRange -> {{-1.5, 4}, {0, 1}}], 
  Graphics[{Black, Disk[xy[t, m1, m2], r1], Red, 
    Disk[zy[t, m1, m2], r2]}],
  AspectRatio -> Automatic], {t, 0, 15}, {m1, 0.01, 6}, {m2, 0.01, 6}]
```

[image]

Comment: Most likely `traj1` and `traj2` do not contain a list of numerical pairs. `ListPlot` appears to be ignoring the `PlotRange` option with empty data in version 11.3 but it does not ignore it in version 12.0.  However, the bigger issue may be that you are not getting numerical results.

Comment: Look what `Table[{t, m1, m2}, {t, 0, 10, 100}, {m1, 0.01, 6, 100}, {m2, 0.01, 6}] ` does. Since step size for to is 100, it is larger than maximum of t. You get only the t-value 0. The same with m1.